# HP ProLiant DL360 G7 Server reconfigure iLO using ipmitool

Tags: hp, ilo, ipmitool

I am struggling with an HP machine that has an iLO card that for some reason has gone off the radar. I can ping the card, but that's pretty much everything I can do with it.
The host is running a trimmed down version of RHEL5.8, so I can't install the HP native utilities, I can use ipmitool though.

So far, I have been able to reconfigure ther card's IP address usinf `ipmitool set 2 ipsrc static` and the rest of the commands to configure the IP, gateway, netmask etc, and the card is now pingable. Here's what it looks like:

```
# ipmitool lan print 2
Set in Progress         : Set Complete
Auth Type Support       :
Auth Type Enable        : Callback :
                        : User     :
                        : Operator :
                        : Admin    :
                        : OEM      :
IP Address Source       : Static Address
IP Address              : 10.1.0.36
Subnet Mask             : 255.255.0.0
MAC Address             : 78:e7:d1:62:4e:c0
BMC ARP Control         : ARP Responses Enabled, Gratuitous ARP Disabled
Default Gateway IP      : 10.1.255.254
802.1q VLAN ID          : Disabled
802.1q VLAN Priority    : 0
Cipher Suite Priv Max   : Not Available
```

So I go ahead and try to configure access like so:

```
# ipmitool lan set 2 auth ADMIN MD5
# ipmitool lan set 2 access on
Set Channel Access for channel 2 failed: Unknown (0x83)
```

Has anyone experienced this before? What can I do to reset the iLO and get back to having access to it?

Thanks,
/me

EDIT:

```
# nmap -p0 10.1.0.36

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-11-18 03:35 CET
Nmap scan report for host-ilo.mydomain.com (10.1.0.36)
Host is up (0.00017s latency).
PORT  STATE    SERVICE
0/tcp filtered unknown
MAC Address: 78:E7:D1:62:4E:C0 (Hewlett Packard)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.35 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

And you can't browse or SSH to the ILO? What does an `nmap` scan show?

You only need to install the [hponcfg utility for your OS](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091409&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_63b882503e2644e795698b9ac4%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) to obtain the ILO's configuration and/or reset the device. It's a single RPM.

`hponcfg -w filename.xml` will write the device configuration to filename.xml.

`hponcfg -r` resets the device to factory defaults.

I'd also recommend a firmware update to your ILO and (system). A firmware update initiated from the host OS will also reset the ILO device. That's beyond the scope of this question, but many people don't keep their HP server firmware up-to-date.

---

Edit: If the ILO is in *shared mode* (versus using its dedicated NIC port), you won't be able to see it from the host server. Keep that in mind. Have you attempted a connection to the ILO via http or SSH from another host?

Comment: Added the nmap scan output. There is no ssh or http access at all, only icmp response. As for installing RPMs, that's exactly what I cannot do on this host unfortunately. And since this is a remote system, I can't reboot it with a liveCD because I have no iLO access...

Comment: Please see my edit above...

Comment: As for not being able to install utilities, that means that this host's health agents and other useful monitoring tools aren't in place. If you need `hponcfg` to do the job, then it is what it is, and is entirely justifiable. Otherwise, I think you're SOL on this.

Comment: Well, the distribution on this host is RHEV-H, and a pretty outdated RHEV-H at that. I have been googling about and it seems like ipmitool should be enough to handle this issue, but the error gets in the way

Comment: But you can still get the hponcfg command onto an RHEV host. That's the right way to handle this.

Comment: I've tried to install the RPM manually, moreover, I've tried to push the files it contains into the right directories, it just doesn't work. The newer RHEV hosts based on RHEL6 have a means of installing RPMs, but this is the old RHEL5 based RHEV-H, basically a stripped down liveCD image, written to the local disks and running in r/o mode. That makes it very secure, but obviously limits my options there

Comment: You can try the ESXi version or extract the RHEL5 RPM... You'll need the binary and the .so files: `/sbin/hponcfg`, `/usr/lib/hponcfg`, `/usr/lib/hponcfg/libhponcfg.so`

Comment: nope, for hponcfg to work I also need the full hp-ilo package, and for that I need to have kernel-devel in place, which takes me even deeper into dependency hell on a distro with no `yum` or internet access.